# Обращение к свойствам и методам объекта

Tags: ооп, php

Изучая углубленно ООП программирование на языке PHP, столкнулся с такой вещью, как разные способы обращения к свойствам и методам объекта. Объясните мне пожалуйста в чем разница между двумя этими способами обращения? Специально сделано две альтернативы работы с объектами или же как?

Способ первый:

```
class Math {
  public static $count = 0;
  public static function getSin($x) {
   self::$count++
   return sin($x); 
  } 
}
echo Math::getSin(1)."<br/>";
echo Math::$count;
```

Способ второй:

```
class Math {
  public $count = 0;
  public function getSin($x) {
   $this->$count++
   return sin($x); 
  } 
}
$M = new Math();
echo $M->getSin(1)."<br/>";    
echo $M->$count;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В первом варианте ты создаешь статические св-ва и методы.

Таким образом ты не сможешь создать 2 объекта, у которых будут разные значения свойства. Даже если ты и создашь два объекта этого класса, к статическим свойствам не получится обратится через объект.

вот примерчик:

```
class Example{
    public static $static_var = 1;
    public $not_static_var = 5;
}

echo Example::$static_var; // вернет 1

Example::$static_var = 2;

echo Example::$static_var; // вернет 2

$obj1 = new Example();
$obj2 = new Example();

echo $obj1->static_var; // ОШИБКА! Нет у объекта такого свойства, это 
                        // статическое свойство, к нему обращаться вот так
                        // Example::$static_var

echo $obj1->not_static_var; // Вернет 5
$obj1->not_static_var = 10;
echo $obj1->not_static_var; // Вернет 10

echo $obj2->not_static_var; // По прежнему 5

echo Example::$static_var; // по прежнему вернет 2
```

Если создавать не статическое свойство, то у каждого объекта будет своё значение )

И еще такой момент. Из статических методов нельзя обращаться к не статическим свойствам. Даже если они в одном классе. Ну это логично, так как статический метод мы можем вызвать не создавая объекта, а не статическое свойство появится только при создании объекта. Вот как-то так, если на пальцах объяснять =)

Comment: спасибо, хорошо все объяснил! Плюсую!

Answer (score 3):

Оператор разрешения области видимости (::) позволяет обратиться к статическим методам или константам класса без создания объекта - экземпляра этого класса.